# Automated weighted counts in a Pivot Table (Excel)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, pivot-table

I have data for sales people who work with different clients. Sometimes the sales person has multiple deals with the same client. I want to be able to work out the count for each sales person for each client - however, I don't want a multi deal to be added as a whole twice. For instance if sales person A does business with company X twice, I want the count to be 1 and .25 (total of 1.25) rather than 2. Then each additional piece of business with company X get's added again as .25

Comment: What's the aspect you're stuck on?  The math for the "partial credit" would be: 0.75+0.25*count.

Comment: @fixer1234 - well the math part sure was the first one I was stuck on (so thanks) - the next is how to get it in the field since I can't edit it..

Comment: You'll need to provide more information about the spreadsheet for that part.  For anyone to help, they will need to understand what's there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether it's possible only in pivot table.

Alternatively you can insert a new column where you calculate a corrected number and sum it in the pivot table. I've used the formula based on fixer1234's comment, but with a more sophisticated one you can get also `1` for first instances and `0.25` for the others.

`=0.75/COUNTIFS([Sales],[@Sales],[Client],[@Client])+0.25`

[image]